# Mobikwik Dashboard dashboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, slider

I want to achieve something like this...[Mobikwik dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYmZ1.jpg)

How can I achieve it? Are there any libraries for creating something like that?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005695/cover-flow-feature-using-view-pager-android

Answer (score 2):

It is Carousel Effect, which is mainly implemented for iOS.

Here it is for Android:

```
package com.carouseleffect;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;

public class CarouselEffectTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    private int maxTranslateOffsetX;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public CarouselEffectTransformer(Context context) {
        this.maxTranslateOffsetX = dp2px(context, 180);
    }


    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
        if (viewPager == null) {
            viewPager = (ViewPager) view.getParent();
        }

        int leftInScreen = view.getLeft() - viewPager.getScrollX();
        int centerXInViewPager = leftInScreen + view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        int offsetX = centerXInViewPager - viewPager.getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        float offsetRate = (float) offsetX * 0.48f / viewPager.getMeasuredWidth();
        float scaleFactor = 1 - Math.abs(offsetRate);
        if (scaleFactor > 0.5) {
            view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
            view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            view.setTranslationX(-maxTranslateOffsetX * offsetRate);
        }

    }

    private int dp2px(Context context, float dipValue) {
        float m = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        return (int) (dipValue * m + 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Main Activity which is Handle Pager transformer and Adapter

```
package com.carouseleffect;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewpagerTop, viewPagerBackground;
    public static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_TOP = 1;
    public static final int ADAPTER_TYPE_BOTTOM = 2;

    private int[] listItems = {R.mipmap.img1, R.mipmap.img2, R.mipmap.img3, R.mipmap.img4,
            R.mipmap.img5, R.mipmap.img6, R.mipmap.img7, R.mipmap.img8, R.mipmap.img9, R.mipmap.img10, R.mipmap.logo, R.mipmap.powered,R.mipmap.img1, R.mipmap.img2, R.mipmap.img3, R.mipmap.img4,
            R.mipmap.img5, R.mipmap.img6, R.mipmap.img7, R.mipmap.img8, R.mipmap.img9, R.mipmap.img10, R.mipmap.logo, R.mipmap.powered,R.mipmap.img1, R.mipmap.img2, R.mipmap.img3, R.mipmap.img4,
            R.mipmap.img5, R.mipmap.img6, R.mipmap.img7, R.mipmap.img8, R.mipmap.img9, R.mipmap.img10, R.mipmap.logo, R.mipmap.powered,R.mipmap.img1, R.mipmap.img2, R.mipmap.img3, R.mipmap.img4,
            R.mipmap.img5, R.mipmap.img6, R.mipmap.img7, R.mipmap.img8, R.mipmap.img9, R.mipmap.img10, R.mipmap.logo, R.mipmap.powered};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
        setupViewPager();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize all required variables
     */
    private void init() {
        viewpagerTop = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerTop);
        viewPagerBackground = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerbackground);

        viewpagerTop.setClipChildren(false);
//        viewpagerTop.setPageMargin(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pager_margin));
        viewpagerTop.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        viewpagerTop.setPageTransformer(false, new CarouselEffectTransformer(this)); // Set transformer
    }

    /**
     * Setup viewpager and it's events
     */
    private void setupViewPager() {
        // Set Top ViewPager Adapter
        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this, listItems, ADAPTER_TYPE_TOP);
        viewpagerTop.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Set Background ViewPager Adapter
//        MyPagerAdapter adapterBackground = new MyPagerAdapter(this, listItems, ADAPTER_TYPE_BOTTOM);
//        viewPagerBackground.setAdapter(adapterBackground);


        viewpagerTop.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            private int index = 0;

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                index = position;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                int width = viewPagerBackground.getWidth();
                viewPagerBackground.scrollTo((int) (width * position + width * positionOffset), 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    viewPagerBackground.setCurrentItem(index);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Handle all click event of activity
     */
    public void clickEvent(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.linMain:
                if (view.getTag() != null) {
                    int poisition = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Poistion: " + poisition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Adapter Class

```
package com.carouseleffect;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    Context context;
    int[] listItems;
    int adapterType;

    public MyPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] listItems, int adapterType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.adapterType=adapterType;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cover, null);
        try {

            LinearLayout linMain = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linMain);
            ImageView imageCover = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageCover);
            linMain.setTag(position);

            switch (adapterType)
            {
                case MainActivity.ADAPTER_TYPE_TOP:
                    linMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shadow);
                    break;
                case MainActivity.ADAPTER_TYPE_BOTTOM:
                    linMain.setBackgroundResource(0);
                    break;
            }

            Glide.with(context).load(listItems[position]).into(imageCover);

            container.addView(view);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == object);
    }
}
```