# How to implement a cover view viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, transformation

I want to implement a viewpager like the one below 
[image: CoverView]

I found this example [Cover Flow feature using view pager android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36005695/cover-flow-feature-using-view-pager-android) but it only inflates the image to the left and does't show the other two to its side.

Comment: Checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36005695/1384010) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36057424/1384010).
Hope it will help you !!!

Comment: @AdarshYadav it's the same one i have linked above. I tried it but it didn't work as expected.

Comment: Alright but it works fine for me. @Alex Kombo

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
viewpager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewpager.setPadding(left,0,right,0);
```

To set margin between two pages

```
viewpager.setPageMargin(10);
```